# Why are some files so huge ( > 26MB) in nextJS exported Page?

Tags: next.js

I've created a webpage with nextjs and use `next export` to create an static page of it.
I wonder why there are files with huge filesize in the output-directory (see: [image: screenshot])

The page is pretty fast if I upload it to the server and run it in the browser. It seems that at least - even if the files `_app.js` and `_index.js`exist in this directory - they are not used by the live-page.

But I wonder why are they so huge, and why they are in the output directory if not needed for production?

--

I'd analysed the bundle with "Webpack Bundle Analyzer" and still don't see, what the cause of such a huge filesize:
[image]

--

I've created a [tiny project](https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/tree/master/examples/next-9) from github and also run `next build` and `next export`, there is no `_app.js`, or `_error.js` at all in the output directory, but only the ones with the random-string in filename!

So might this depend on a miss configuration of my Environment?

Answer (score 5):

## I found the reason of this BUG!

*It's a bit complicated, so I describe it step by step.*

Let's say you have a clean Project, you never build.
You do `next build` and `next export`, and the `/out`-Directory is created. *(That's the expected behavior!)*

> If you have no clean project, you can simulate it with doing this steps on an existing Project:
>
> 1. remove directories: .next, out, node-modules
> 2. yarn install
> 3. yarn next build
> 4. yarn next export

For my current Project, this result in a /out-Directory with size of round about 5 MB.

so far: **ALL FINE!**

Now we reproduce the BUG:

1. do `next dev`
2. now - while `next dev` is still running, do a new `next build`
3. at least do `next export`

You will find now some files in your `/out`-Directory, which are not needed for the live-enviroment (and shouldn't be there at all!). They will have a size somewhere in the range of MegaByte. (In my case it was _app.js, [pages].js... but I think it will be one file for each of your pages at least. You easily find them if you know, that they don't have an random-string in the filename)

For my project, the file-size for the `out`-Directory raised from round about 5 MB to round 20 MB

## Additional important facts:

Stopping the `next dev` Process and running `next export` again ***WON'T fix*** the issue!
**You need to fully erase all content in your `.next`-Directory to fix this.**

In a perfect World, the `next export` process should recognize, if there currently is `next dev` in Progress and give an error-message that this process first need to be closed.

Comment: It works for me, but still after a clean build Idk why we have a `cache` folder(inside .next) that takes 90% of .next fold size even though the server didn't start yet, do you think we can work around it, or we just delete it